# Is it possible to display image file thumbnails with "CMFCShellListCtrl"?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on MFC project based on [VCSamples in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/Explorer). This project similar "Windows Explorer.exe" (Under picture).

[image: VCSample project Default setting (Large icon)]

I know that select button of "Large Icons" ,"Small Icons" "Details" and "List" is can change file list view. **But I want large size of Thumbnails for Image file like windows real explorer.exe (Under picture)**

[image: I want like this picture]

I searched for information about "CMFCShellListCtrl", but there was no information or only information on "CMFCShellTreeCtrl". ("CMFCShellListCtrl" is in 'ExplorerView.h/.cpp' in VCSamples project)

Did I misunderstand? Or Should I customize "CMFCShellListCtrl"?

Comment: I don't have an answer for `CMFCShellListCtrl`. AFAIK these controls only try to simulate Explorer, so they propably won't support its latest features. They also don't have the same look and feel as Explorer. I suggest to use [`IExplorerBrowser`](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/17809/host-windows-explorer-in-your-applications-using-t) which is the real Explorer control. It supports thumbnail view out-of-the-box.

Comment: @zett42 Thank you for reply. I will try your link